# re-evaluating an evaluate function when a cell reference in a string is changed

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using a VBA function to evaluate strings as functions:

```
Public Function eval(s As String) As Variant
    eval = Evaluate(s)
End Function
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to modify the function so that when a reference within the string is changed the evaluated function is updated? I expect not but I'm hoping I'm wrong!

For instance, as an example `"EVAL("IF(A1=TRUE,1,0)")`, I'm hoping there is a way so that when `A1` is update the function is re-evaluated.

I'm also hoping this can be done in an efficient way.

Many thanks.

Comment: You'd have to make it volatile by adding `application.volatile true`.

Comment: Any change this is an [xy-problem](https://xyproblem.info/)? Do you really need to create a volatile UDF just to update the outcome when the content of `A1` changes? Why not just regular functions?